# Date time picker validations

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am sorry for posting this question as it may be find silly to all, but I am not getting the exact solution.

The question is: I have a Date time picker in my project, it comes after the 3 textboxes in the form, if there is no text is entered in the textbox and enter on submit, it gives a message(validation) that data to be entered. In the same way, if the date is not selected, it should proceed further.

What is the code to do that, the code which worked for other textboxes and not working for datetimepicker control is:

```
       if (dateInsert.Value.ToString() = string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select date!");
            dateInsert.Focus();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: I would check if the Date is valid via:
`DateTime _temp;
DateTime.TryParse(dtPicker.Value.ToString(), out _temp);`
If this is true, then the DateTime is valid.

Comment: Check if your code works after putting == in if (dateInsert.Value.ToString() == string.Empty)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please correct the code and see if it works

```
               if (dateInsert.Value.ToString() == "")
              {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select date!");
                dateInsert.Focus();
                return;
               }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct solution to empty `DateTimePicker`. Only way to empty DateTimePicker is to set `CustomFormat` and then set `empty space` as value.

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
```

Even if you do it value will be cleared in the control but if you access the value property of the control in code it will return the current date time. So your condition will always be false.

```
//This is always false
dateInsert.Value.ToString() = string.Empty
```

**SOLUTION**

Instead of using `Value` use `Text`in the condition.

```
if(dateInsert.Text = " ")
```

Comment: If I am using the code you provided, the datetimepicker value is going to null, I am very about it, but it solved only half problem, remaining is that, here even  though I did not select the date it is getting submitted, If I did not select/change the date the value should not be submitted. I am sorry for causing confusion.

Comment: @karthikreddy Are you clearing the datetimepicker value on form load ? what is the value it initially holds ? default date time ?

Comment: Yes, I am clearing from form load only and value I am getting is today's date.

Comment: @karthikreddy So Current date is invalid ? i mean users are only allowed to enter future or past dates ?

Comment: Yes, the users should select the past date. The form should not be submitted until the user selects the date. Thanks for your patience in working with me.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using visual studio.....use this code to validate empty textbox

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Display="None"
        ErrorMessage="Select Date" ControlToValidate="dateInsert" ValidationGroup="validation"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: I am coding in c# for a windows forms.

Comment: [link]http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/DtpValidation03252007045710AM/DtpValidation.aspx

check this...it may help you...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateInsert.Text)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select date!");
            dateInsert.Focus();
            return;
           }
```

hope this helps someone

Answer (score -1):

```
if(datepicker.Text == " ")
messagebox.show("Please Select Date");

// this works 100 %
```