# Proper way for datepickers validaton in c#? (windows forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, datepicker

Just can't get it with `datepicker` validation.
I have `datepicker` **From** and `datepicker` **To**, so I want to prevent the user from doing some kung fu and seting `datepicker` **From** to be bigger than `datepicker` **To**, I've bumped across some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738498/date-time-picker-validations) but couldn't find the answer, so I've tried doing the easiest way I could think of:

Set `MaxDate` property for `datepicker` **from** in `form_load` event

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     datepickerFrom.MaxDate = datepickerFrom.Value;
}
```

Then do the same for `value_changed` event

```
private void datepickerFrom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    datepickerFrom.MaxDate = datepickerFrom.Value;
}
```

This was easy and fine, only few lines of code, and I've only needed `datepickerFrom_ValueChanged` event, but recently I've tried **typing** date into `datepicker` insted of selecting it, and then all hell broke loose.
So I came to some solution for validation, instead of setting `MaxDate` property, I've tried this.

```
private void dtFrom_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    DateTime from = datepickerFrom.Value;
    DateTime to = datepickerTo.Value;
    int year= from.Year > to.Year ? to.Year : from.Year;
    int month = from.Month > to.Month ? to.Month : from.Month;
    int day = from.Day > to.Day ? to.Day : from.Day;
    int hour = from.Hour > to.Hour ? to.Hour : from.Hour;
    int minute = from.Minute > to.Minute ? to.Minute : from.Minute;
    int second = from.Second > to.Second ? to.Second : from.Second;
    //setting datepicker value
    datepickerFrom.Value = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

}
```

This works fine, but feels like bit of headache, and I have to do this for `datepickerTO_ValueChanged` event also, sure I could make one `method` and call it two times, but still feels like there is a batter way for this, so any suggestions?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Am I missing something? Can't you just check if From greater than To?

Comment: So your actual problem description, derived from your description "all hell broke loose", is something like _"When typing a date into a WinForms DatePicker it ignores the MaxDate property"_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution 1:

You can handle `datePickerTo` close event and do something like:

```
private void dateTimePickerTo_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerFrom.Value);
    DateTime todate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerTo.Value);
    if (fromdate > todate1)
        //Error
}
```

You can also use `DateTime.Compare` whcih get two date 
like

```
int result = DateTime.Compar(dateTimePickerFrom.Value ,dateTimePickerTo.Value);
```

if `result` is `1` means `From` date is earlier, [see this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx).

**Note1:**

but as you said if user type in From or To textboxes then `closeup` event never fire so you need compare them in where you want to process 
 such as button click.

**Note2:**

As @Sinatr comment if Value is `DateTime` then don't need to convert it so the code would be like:

```
 if (dateTimePickerFrom.Value >dateTimePickerTo.Value)
        //Error
```

Comment: Why not use [Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property? Then you don't need to use `Convert`.

Comment: @Sinatr, Edited before seeing your comment, Thank you.

Comment: nice suggestion, but where do you suggest to put this line of code? should i put it in `datepickerTo_ValueChanged` event? that wou'd maybe cause some problem when trying to type in date instead of selecting, let me try it

Comment: @Yollo As I mentioned put my suggested code in `CloseUp` event of `To` datepicker, or in a method and call it when user type date completely not `change` event.

Comment: @Yollo , Focus on Note1 , why you are insisting to check date in texboxes event ? isn't it better to check them in a separate method and call that method everywhere you want, such as button click (main process) .

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal would lead to a horrible interface. Suppose the following case:

```
From = 1 jan 2000
To = 1 feb 2000
```

User wants to change both values to 2010. He starts with the from value:

```
From = 1 jan 2010
```

Now he wants to change the TO value to 1 feb 2010. Alas, he can't.

Proper usage would be: add some button with which the operator can affirm he has changed all data, start checking it and update. In windows this button is usually named **Apply Now** or **OK**. Why deviate from this windows standard.

```
private void OnFormLoading(object sender, ...)
{
    this.FromDate.MinValue = ... // use the real absolute min value you want ever to allow
    this.FromDate.MaxValue = ...;
    this.ToDate.MinValue = ...;
    this.ToDate.MaxValue = ...;
}
```

Don't do any checking as long as the operator is making changes. Strat checking the input values when he indicates that he finished making changes:

```
private void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    bool InputOk = CheckInput();
    if (!inputOk)
    {
         ShowIncorrectInput(); // for instance using a MessageBox
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for pointing and suggestions, It's just i am implementing this in large forms, so I've wanted to cut the validation in `value_changed event`, , would  `_close` or `_leave` event be the same as apply now button?

Comment: So add an apply-now in a group box with the two dates. If name is confusing, use something like "accept"